# Java: How to import a variable in another file?

Tags: java, eclipse

*Please* read the bottom before doing anything (but it might be long)

I am trying to make a text-based Minecraft Server, and I'm having trouble in Mines.java. I want to import the integer 'money' into [you'll see the 7-slash comments] in Mines.java, from Main.java. I tried `import [package].Main.main.money`, but that didn't work.

I am using Mars.1 Eclipse.

**Main.java**

```
// NOTE: Please read 'cc.txt' in src folder before modifying

package com.quaggles.main;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    // System.out.println(""); (to copy)
    // System objects
    static boolean running = true;
    static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    static String input;
    static String username;
    // Game variables
    static int coins = 100;
    static int level = 1;
    // Methods that may come in handy
    public static void PETC() {
        System.out.println("Press enter to continue...");
        try {
            System.in.read();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle any exceptions
        }
    }
    // Doesn't work in java console (sorry Eclipse users) (still testing)
    public static void clearConsole() {
        try {
            final String os = System.getProperty("os.name");

            if (os.contains("Windows")) {
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cls");
            } else {
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("clear");
            }
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            // Handle any exceptions
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        USER: while (running) {
            System.out.println("What is your username:");
            input = in.nextLine();
            if (input.equals("")) {
                System.out.println("You typed nothing! Please try again.");
                PETC();
                clearConsole();
                continue USER;
            } else {
                username = input;
                break USER;
            }
        }
        clearConsole();
        System.out.println("Running on " + System.getProperty("os.name") + "\n");
        System.out.println("Welcome to...");
        System.out.println("   _____                           _____            __ _");
        System.out.println("  / ____|                         / ____|          / _| |");
        System.out.println(" | (___   ___ _ ____   _____ _ __| |     _ __ __ _| |_| |_");
        System.out.println("  \\___ \\ / _ \\ '__\\ \\ / / _ \\ '__| |    | '__/ _` |  _| __|");
        System.out.println("  ____) |  __/ |   \\ V /  __/ |  | |____| | | (_| | | | |_");
        System.out.println(" |_____/ \\___|_|    \\_/ \\___|_|   \\_____|_|  \\__,_|_|  \\__|\n");
        System.out.println("    v0.0.1 beta");
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("ServerCraft is a project made by Quaggle\n" + "that tries to answer the question:\n"
                + "What if a Minecraft server was text based?");
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------\n");
        PETC();
        clearConsole();
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
        GAME: while (running) {
            input = in.nextLine().toLowerCase();
            if (input.equals("exit")) {
                break GAME;
            } else if (input.equals("help")) {
                clearConsole();
                System.out.println("HELP");
                System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("help - shows all* commands");
                System.out.println("stats - shows your stats");
                System.out.println("updates - show any updates on the game");
                System.out.println("mine - go to the mines");
                System.out.println("home");
                System.out.println("exit - quits the game :(\n");
                System.out.println("*not actually all - find them out yourself ;)");
                PETC();
                clearConsole();
                continue GAME;
            } else if (input.equals("stats")) {
                System.out.println("STATISTICS");
                System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("Coins: " + coins);
                System.out.println("Level " + level);
                PETC();
                clearConsole();
                continue GAME;
            } else if (input.equals("updates")) {
                System.out.println("UPDATES");
                System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("1-8-16 - PRECIOUS");
                System.out.println("Added mining and a money system\n");
                System.out.println("1-7-16 - Mr. Krabs! I have an idea!");
                System.out.println("I finally started working on the game after countless reconsiderations & regrets!");
            } else if (input.equals("mine")) {
                com.quaggles.main.Mines.mine();
            } else {
                System.out.println("\'" + input + "\' is not a command.");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Thanks for playing, " + username + "!");
        PETC();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

**Mines.java**

```
// NOTE: Please read 'cc.txt' in src folder before modifying
// WORK IN PROGRESS: I am still working on this, (may be very buggy)

package com.quaggles.main;

import java.util.Scanner;

import com.quaggles.main.Main.*; //unneeded at the moment

public class Mines {
    // System objects
    static boolean running = true;
    static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    static String input;
    /////// Import 'money' from Main.java
    static int pickaxe = 1;
    static int pickaxeXP = 0;
    static int pickaxeLevelUp = 100;
    // Game variables
    public static void mine() {
        GAME: while (running) {
            System.out.println("Welcome to the...");
            System.out.println("  __  __ _                 ");
            System.out.println(" |  \\/  (_)                ");
            System.out.println(" | \\  / |_ _ __   ___  ___ ");
            System.out.println(" | |\\/| | | '_ \\ / _ \\/ __|");
            System.out.println(" | |  | | | | | |  __/\\__ \\");
            System.out.println(" |_|  |_|_|_| |_|\\___||___/");
            System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Type \'mine\' to start mining");
            input = in.nextLine();
            if (input.equals("mine")) {
                /////// money
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I just realized 'money' doesn't exist and I forgot I renamed it to 'coins', that should clear up any confusion.

Ok, i'll try and be as in-depth as possible.

Some person said on my 'how to execute another file thing' that maybe I should take a java programming course and not learn a programming language by Stack Overflow, and I respect that.

I just wanna make this clear, I like to learn things my own special way. I'm 11, and from my perspective, all the courses on youtube either explain things too slowly that by episode 11 we will be still learning about integer, or they move into things too quickly. And the ones that *aren't* on youtube cost money, so don't recommend me anything, It's fine. Besides, you don't *have* to answer. Thank you whoever that was.

Comment: For **11**-year old it is impressive indeed.

Comment: Please expand on "*it did not work*".  What actually happens?

Comment: While I understand that you want to 'learn in your own way', it may still help to look through books or take other free courses like https://www.udacity.com/course/intro-to-java-programming--cs046 or https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ . The key thing is that programming uses a "language" and you need to be able to communicate in it. At this point I don't know where the money methods (think doors) to your class (think house) are supposed to connect. I'll now get off my high horse. Props for trying at 11.

Comment: A text based mine craft server? Good luck lol... I sense much ASCII in your future youngling...

Comment: Consider providing constructive and encouraging comments to the (11 year old) OP, @AshwinGupta.

Comment: Also I get what you are saying about leaning your own way. I respect that. I'm 14 and I haven't taken any courses. I have been learning through online documentation and tutorials. Also I have a book for beginners Java is by herbert schildt. It's a great book it's 20 dollars but it's worth it and you will learn a ton. Although maybe not since you may know it all now. For graphics in Java2d I have been using the java doc and zetcode.com. Try that website it's great. In general stack overflow, Java doc, tutorialspoint.com, and other online resources are the best.

Comment: @JanNielsen see the next comment I just finished writing. Also I was just saying that cuz I have done many text based projects and gone absolutely bonkers trying to work with ascii art. You should've seen my battleship game...

Comment: Out of curiosity Quang what are you using for the minecraft API? I have always wanted to try to do a mine craft plugin or mod. I know forge offers a good one for mods but I have not had the time or patience to learn it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer your specific question as best as possible first. There is no variable named `money` in the class `com.quaggles.main.Main` but there is a `coins` variable so if that's the variable you mean, here's how:

**Mines.java**:

```
        if (input.equals("mine")) {
            System.out.println("My coins are: " + Main.coins);
        }
```

**Note 1**: classes in the same Java package (i.e. namespace) do not need to `import`, nor do they need to fully specify the namespace, so you can simply reference `Main` and `Mines` (i.e., without the namespace `com.quaggles.main`).

**Note 2**: since `Main.coins` is `static` there is only a single instance of this `coins` in the server; presumably, that means the server can only handle one player.

**Note 3**: `Main` calls `Mines.mines()` and `Mines` then calls `Main.coins` -- this is called a [circular reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference). As professionals, we work hard to avoid circular references because they can cause unpredictable behavior. Consider refactoring your code, perhaps to include a list of `Account`s, i.e., one for each player which contains the `coins` or `money`.

Good luck with your learning, and don't get discouraged by negative comments.